# How to change RUs in Cosmos DB according to time of the day?

Tags: database, azure, azure-cosmosdb

How to change RUs in Cosmos DB according to time of the day, for example higher RUs allowance in daytime and lower during the night?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot do that natively, yet, in Cosmos DB. So you are left with workarounds, which are plenty:

1. Build job on some ci system that would trigger at certain time and do the scaling
2. Azure Automation runbook with schedules
3. Timer trigger Azure Function\Webjob
4. probably dozen other ways, like cron on some vm, etc